# How can I fetch the build versions from Artifactory repository

Tags: artifactory

I have to fetch the list of builds present here : https://openmrs.jfrog.io/openmrs/public/org/openmrs/api/openmrs-api/

I am new to artifactory and its api. I need to know the curl command for fetching all the version numbers mentioned there please? How do I go about it? It's worthwhile to know that the repo doesn't belong to me and hence I do not have the username and password for it(Incase that's needed).

In the artifactory rest API documentation they use localhost for this purpose and do not have such a link. I haven't set this repo up so I do not know how it's done. Basically I am new to this and hence any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you would like to get the list of versions available in this folder, there are 2 possible options:

1) Use the [folder info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FolderInfo) REST API method to get a list of all the sub-folders

```
 curl https://openmrs.jfrog.io/openmrs/api/storage/public/org/openmrs/api/openmrs-api/
```

2) Download and parse the [maven-metadata.xml](https://openmrs.jfrog.io/openmrs/public/org/openmrs/api/openmrs-api/maven-metadata.xml) file inside this folder. This file contains information about available versions.

Comment: Thanks a ton . Exactly what I needed :)